# Cannot import go SSE library from my terminal

Tags: go, backend, server-sent-events

Currently, I am trying to import the [r3labs SSE library](https://github.com/r3labs/sse) by running the command in the README, go get github.com/r3labs/sse/v2. However, when I do this, I am getting this error,

```
cannot find package "github.com/r3labs/sse/v2" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/r3labs/sse/v2 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/avidave/go/src/github.com/r3labs/sse/v2 (from $GOPATH)
```

I just checked my env variables, and for my $GOROOT and $GOPATH, I have

```
GOPATH="/home/user/go"  
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
```

Currently, in my local, I don't have a github.com folder and neither am I allowed to create one, so I am not sure how to go about this. I am also a little new to golang, so I am not sure how importing modules work fully, but I have been able to import other libraries accordingly, like mux just fine.

Comment: Did you try the `-u` flag for go get? So `go get -u github.com/r3labs/sse/v2`

Comment: I tried to do that just right now, and it still didn't work

Comment: Use module builds. It‘s 2021.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first: use `go mod init <name_project>` command,

second : use `go get github.com/name/of/package` command,

just it.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure how go modules worked, I have yet to still understand it better in-depth, but I am glad this worked and getting me started!